# Looping through elements of set

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a seteq which can have any number of elements (the elements are integers). For example

```
#<seteq: 1 2 3>
```

How do I loop through the elements of this set randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `for` comprehension:

```
(for ([item (in-set my-set)])
  (displayln item))
```